# Unable to show custom customer attribute only in adminhtml customer form

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

I have created some custom customer attribute that I need to show only in admin customer form. 
For these attributes i used in my InstallData `'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer']`

In `customer_form_attribute` my attribute code matches the used_in_form code but I'm able to show it in admin only if I add `'used_in_forms' => ['customer_account_edit']`, but this way it is shown also in the frontend.

Is there a way to show it only on the admin side?

**EDIT:**

Here is upgrade code

```
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();
    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2', '<')) {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'my_attribute', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'My attribute label',
            'input' => 'boolean',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
            'default' => 1,
        ]);
        //add attribute to attribute set
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'my_attribute')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
            ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }

    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

Comment: Can you update your installer code?

Comment: @SukumarGorai I added the code

Comment: which magento version are you using ?

Comment: @PradeepSanku I'm using Magento 2.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to work this by following code:

```
$attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'my_attribute');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $usedInForms);
$attribute->save();
```

I have changed the **addData** to **setData** and not passing anything else.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code

```
<?php
    $customerSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        'my_attribute',
        [
            'label' => 'My attribute label',
            'system' => 0,
            'position' => 999,
            'sort_order' =>999,
            'visible' =>  true,
            'note' => '',
            'type' => 'int',
            'input' => 'boolean',
        ]
    );

    $customerSetup->getEavConfig()
                ->getAttribute('customer', 'my_attribute')
                ->setData('is_user_defined',1)
                ->setData('is_required',0)
                ->setData('default_value','')
                ->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer'])
                ->save();
?>
```

Even after above code if the field is not visible in backend try adding customer_form.xml at view/base/ui_component/ of your module with following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="customer">
        <field name="my_attribute" formElement="checkbox">
            <settings>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```